# How to Sending sms and email using Dart (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build and app in flutter which sends email and SMS. Purpose is to reset password (forgot Password). But I am not able to find a suitable package for it. The email or SMS should be sent with out user interaction once they click reset password. The SMS and email will be sent from their mobile to the very same number or email.

Any alternate suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Email, you can use this mailer package => https://pub.dev/packages/mailer

**Update:**
If this function didn't work then lower your mailer package version.

Example:

```
Future<void> sendMail(String name, String otp, String recipientEmail) async {
  // ignore: deprecated_member_use
  SmtpServer smtpServer = gmail('yourEmail', 'Password');
  Message message = Message()
    ..from = address('yourEmail', 'UserName')
    ..recipients.add(recipientEmail)
    ..subject = 'Any Text.'
    ..html = "Any Text.";

  try {
    final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);
    PrintLog.printMessage('Message sent: ' + sendReport.toString());
  } on MailerException catch (e) {
    PrintLog.printMessage('Message not sent. ' + e.toString());
    for (var p in e.problems) {
      PrintLog.printMessage('Problem: ${p.code}: ${p.msg}');
    }
  }
  var connection = PersistentConnection(smtpServer);
  await connection.send(message);
  await connection.close();
}
```

For SMS, you can use Url Launcher Package => https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Example:

```
  _textMe() async {
if (Platform.isAndroid) {
  const uri = 'sms:YourNumber?body=hello%20there';
  await launch(uri);
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
  // iOS
  const uri = 'sms:YourNumber&body=hello%20there';
  await launch(uri);
  }
}
```

Comment: can url launcher be used to send email also?

Comment: yes but I'll open the Gmail app to send mail if you want to programmatically send mail then use the mailer package. If this answer may help you then give the right answer tick. Happy fluttering